# Paraview : grid interpolation and merging data

Tags: vtk, paraview

I have a paraview multiblock dataset containing blocks holding two different vtk UnstructuredGrids. I want to interpolate data from a grid to another and handle them simultaneously.

Here is what I do :

1. I use the `Extract Block` filter twice  to separate the data from the two blocks (please note that the data are still of the "multiblock" type (seen in the information tab)).
2. Using the `Resample With Dataset` filter, I'm able to interpolate the data held on block 2 (coarse grid) on the grid of block 1 (finer grid).

My issue comes on step 3. :

3. I'd like to use the `Append Attributes` filter to handle simultaneously data of block 1 and data interpolated from block 2, but my problem is that this filter is not available.

If the two datasets come from two separate UnstructuredGrids (no multi-block) structures, the `Append Attributes` is available and I can do what I want. 
To circumvent this behavior, I have to apply the `Merge Blocks` filter after step 1. Note that the output of this last filter is not anymore of "multiblock" type but is now of "UnstructuredGrid" type.

This is too tricky and not intuitive, could someone explain what is the rational behind it?

Answer (score 3):

You do not need `Append Attributes` to get both data. Just check the "Pass Point Data" and "Pass Cell Data" checkbox in the `Ressample With DataSet` filter.

As per why `Append Attributes` filter is not available in your case, there can be different reasons. If you are using ParaView 5.8.0, it can tell you why.

Just hover over the grayed-out filter in *Filters -> Alphabetical*, the reason will be written in the status bar.

Comment: I use Paraview 5.4.1 (coming with debian 10). The `Pass Point Data` and `Pass Cell Data` checkboxes you mention seem to be unavailable. Do they also come from more recent versions?

Comment: Indeed they do. You can download a more recent version binary version of ParaView here : https://www.paraview.org/download/